# Angular app detect Array as Object and return error

Tags: angular

In my app I store files in the database, once I have stored the files, I return the ids of the created row in the table to my Angular app to add it to the user information.

When I get the ids, they are returned as Array but, I don't know why, Angular show me an error for an Object element.

Here is the function on my API to store the files and return the ids

```
function uploadFiles(req, res, next) {
  let queries = []
  for (var i = 0; i < req.files.length; i++) {
    queries.push(db.any('insert into public.documents(original_name,mimetype,path) values(' + "'" + 
    req.files[i].originalname + "','" + req.files[i].mimetype + "','" + req.files[i].path + 
    "') returning id_document,original_name"))
  }
  Promise.all(queries).then((data)=>{
    res.json(data);
  },(err)=>{
    console.log('uploadFiles error : ',err)
  })
}
```

Here is how I send the files to the API and then how I get the ids to add them on my user information

```
for (var i = 0; i < this.selectedFiles.length; ++i) {
  let files = this.selectedFiles[i].files
  await this.patientService.uploadFiles(files).then((data)=> {
    console.log(data)
    let result = []
    for (var j = 0; j < data.length; ++j) {
      result.push({'id':data[j][0].id_document,'name':data[j][0].original_name})
    }
    // add result to user information
  })
}
```

And the `uploadFiles` function

```
async uploadFiles(files){
  let formData = new FormData()
  for (var i = 0; i < files.length; ++i) {
    formData.append('files',files[i])
  }
  return await this.httpClient.post(LOCATION_API + 'upload-file', formData).toPromise()
}
```

So here the `console.log(data)` show me this

[image]

And as we can see it's an Array, but here is the error I got

[image]

And finally, what is weird, is that the error is shown, but the app still work. But event if it works, I don't want an error to stay on my app ...

Comment: İs the error and the console log is shown at the same time ? UploadFiles method does not return anything. Can you add the patientService.uploadFiles method ?

Comment: No the error is shown at start when I launch the server. And for the UploadFiles method, I use expressJS so the `res.json(data)` do the job. I have edited with the `uploadFiles` function.

Comment: Can you debug the code ? If you can please write a if block with condition like `!(data instanceOf Array)` and debug the data when condition successful. This error message is misleading.

Comment: There could be global variable named 'data' ?

Comment: @BurakAkyıldız, your first question 'Is the error and the console log is shown at the same time ?' helped me to see that the error comes from the interpretation of the element and not what actually is the element. So by adding a simple `: any[]` on this line `this.patientService.uploadFiles(files).then((data: any[])=> {`, it solved my error. Thanks for your pertinent question :)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you don't pass any information about the type returned by your API so `this.httpClient.post` uses the default and it is `object`.
You can find it in the [documentation](https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpClient#post).

To fix that you need to define the expected return type explicitly as generic argument of `httpClient.post`:

```
interface FileData {
  id_document: string;
  original_name: string;
}

this.httpClient.post<Array<Array<FileData>>(/* ... */);
                    ^---------Here--------^
```

Please also note that `await` is not needed before the promise returned from async function and well as in case when `.then` is used

Comment: Thanks, I have found out a solution thanks to the question of Burak in the comment above, but your answer show me why the data is first detected as Object :)
And for the `await` I think I have just ommited to remove it because I wasn't using `then` before.